# mongo aggregation adding dates and sums

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I feel like this could be really complex. I know this is possible in JS by taking each record, determine the difference in months, then increase each model.month by 1 within a for loop that stops once the months difference has been met. I just can't wrap my head around the possibility with aggregation. Any help would be a lifesaver!

Here is my data:

```
{
   model: car
   serial: bbbaaa
   warranty_start_date: 03/05/2018
   warranty_end_date: 06/16/2018
},
{
   model: car
   serial: jjjwww
   warranty_start_date: 03/02/2018
   warranty_end_date: 05/20/2018
},
{
   model: truck
   serial: tttvvv
   warranty_start_date: 05/06/2016
   warranty_end_date: 07/15/2016
}
```

This is how I want it to end up:

```
{
  model: car
  in_warranty_these_months: { 03/2018: 2, 04/2018: 2, 05/2018: 2, 06/2018: 1 } 
},
{
  model: truck
  in_warranty_these_months: { 05/2016: 1, 06/2016: 1, 07/2016: 1 } 
}
```

**UPDATE**
with major help from @mickl,
the below code works like a charm:

```
 db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            monthsRange: {
                $range: [ 
                    { $add: [ 
                        { $multiply: [12, {$year: "$warranty_start_date"}] }, 
                        {$month: "$warranty_start_date"} ] 
                    }, 
                    { $add: [ 
                        { $multiply: [12, {$year: "$warranty_end_date"}] }, 
                        { $add: [{$month: "$warranty_end_date"}, 1] } ] 
                    }, 1]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$monthsRange"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { model: "$model", month: "$monthsRange" },
            count: {$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id.model",
        pairs: {
          $push: {          
            k: {
              $dateToString: {
                format: "%m_%Y",
                date: {
                  $dateFromParts: {
                    day: 1,
                    month: {
                      $cond: [{
                        $eq: [0, {
                          $mod: ["$_id.month", 12]
                        }]
                      }, {
                        $trunc: 12
                      }, {
                        $mod: ["$_id.month", 12]
                      }]
                    },
                    year: {
                      $cond: [{
                        $eq: [0, {
                          $mod: ["$_id.month", 12]
                        }]
                      }, {
                        $subtract: [{
                          $trunc: {
                            $divide: ["$_id.month", 12]
                          }
                        }, 1]
                      }, {
                        $trunc: {
                          $divide: ["$_id.month", 12]
                        }
                      }]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            v: "$count"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                model: "$_id",
                in_warranty_these_months: {
                    $arrayToObject: "$pairs"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Hey, are warranty_start_date and warranty_end_date strings or dates ?

Comment: They are dates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following aggrregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            monthsRange: {
                $range: [ 
                    { $add: [ 
                        { $multiply: [12, {$year: "$warranty_start_date"}] }, 
                        {$month: "$warranty_start_date"} ] 
                    }, 
                    { $add: [ 
                        { $multiply: [12, {$year: "$warranty_end_date"}] }, 
                        { $add: [{$month: "$warranty_end_date"}, 1] } ] 
                    }, 1]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$monthsRange"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { model: "$model", month: "$monthsRange" },
            count: {$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.model",
            pairs: {
                $push: {
                    k: { 
                        $dateToString: {
                            format: "%m/%Y",
                            date: {
                                $dateFromParts: { 
                                    day: 1, 
                                    month: { $add: [{ $mod: [ "$_id.month", 12 ] }, 1] }, 
                                    year: { $trunc: { $divide: [ "$_id.month", 12 ] } }
                                } 
                            }
                        }                        
                    },
                    v: "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            model: "$_id",
            in_warranty_these_months: {
                $arrayToObject: "$pairs"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you have to generate ranges (using [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/)) based on your dates. To do that you can convert your dates to numbers based on following formula: `12 *year + month`. This will give you a possibility to use $range to generate four values for first document, three values for second, etc.

Then you can use `$group` to count each month per model.

In last step we want to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) so we have to transform our data to objects with two properties, `k` and `v`. To do that we have to transform our numbers back to desired format using [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/index.html) and [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html)

Comment: Wow, this is impressive. I&#39;m still trying to work through addtoset (I need to read docs) but it&#39;s basically adding those dates in between (as numbers)? Me server isn&#39;t running 3.6 yet, I will have to come up with another way to pull the date from the number.  I&#39;m sure another search on stack overflow will help. Thank you so much! Going to try it out in the morning..

Comment: Meant to say addFields. Not addToSet.

Comment: Hah so I ended up updating our DB to 3.6 to take advantage of this. But i'm running into this issue on the last grouping stage. It appears the month calculation is incorrect: 
Command failed with error 40523: ''month' must evaluate to an integer in the range 1 to 12, found 0'

Comment: @JeffFasulkey, edited my answer, all you need to change is to add 1 to month in `$group`, try now

Comment: Thanks again! because mod gave me a zero for december, i ended up putting a cond statement in for the december months which would simply return 12 as the month.